# Claw free Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have been reading this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph)  on how to find if the graph is claw-free or not but I cannot understand some part of it.

Algorithm says(Under the recognition title) "...one can test whether a graph is claw-free by checking for each vertex of the graph, that the complement graph of its neighbors does not contain a triangle".

Now we can test whether a graph(represented in adjacency matrix) contains a triangle or not by simply calculating G*G*G and if its trace(sum of all main diagonal elements) is zero no triangle exits.

What is meant by "for each vertex of the graph, that the complement graph of its neighbors"?

Does it means that I should take Complement of the graph for every vertex and check for triangle or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you should take each vertex and look at the subgraph consisting of all neighbors of that vertex. Then look at its complement graph, which you get bh erasing all current edges between vertices and adding ijn all missing edges.

Look for triangles here, then do this for all other vertices.

Comment: So suppose when I am seeing for vertex "A" in the subgraph I will see  all the vertices reachable by "A". Then for this graph I will take complement and check for triangle. Right...Now this will make that "A" vertex isolated in the complement graph so its row will be zero so while doing G*G*G I will always get a zero. Plz point where am I wrong

Comment: Also I can't understand where will the difference lie if I take complement of the whole Graph G at once. Why with every vertex.

Comment: You can take it all at once, but there might be triangles in the whole complement that don't lie in any little complement. No matger what, you need to see kf there are triangles in each little complement.